# Using CompositionTarget.SurfaceContentsLost Event in UWP for managing RenderTargetBitmap?

Tags: events, uwp, sample, rendertargetbitmap

I was reading up on RenderTargetBitmap for a bug in one of my UWPs where a captured image wasn't displaying correctly.  Came across a remark from Microsoft stating RenderTargetBitmap can lose data for some reason or another and that we should be attempting to render the bitmap a second time using `CompositionTarget.SurfaceContentsLost` event.  But I haven't been able to find an example of this event online.  And I can't seem to request feedback from Microsoft at this time on their Knowledge base site.  Does anyone have some sample code they would be willing to share?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I haven't been able to find an example of this event online.

There's a ImageSourceUpdateRegion sample in [Win2D-UWP-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/ImageSourceUpdateRegion.xaml.cs). It registers the `CompositionTarget.SurfaceContentsLost` event in [UserControl_Loaded](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/ImageSourceUpdateRegion.xaml.cs#L38). You could check this sample to learn how to use this event for your UWP app.

Comment: Thanks for finding the example.  I followed the directions, but my event never fired when it should have on a `Page` in my UWP.  At this point I am just going to start pulling out UI elements until `RenderTargetBitmap` stabilizes.